# Anyway to prevent [FromQuery] from instantiating object?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a search endpoint

```
[HttpGet, Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] SearchCriteria? searchCriteria = null)
{
    if (searchCriteria == null)
        throw Exception("This never happens...")
    else 
       ....
}
```

If I hit the endpoint direct with no search criteria (just `api/search`) the `searchCriteria` object is always instantiated and isn't null. If I remove [FromQuery] it does correctly default to null when no values are provided and only instantiated if provided in the body.

Is there anyway to detect that no query params have been passed to the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.Query.Any()`, or `Request.Query.Count == 0` to check if no parameter was sent

Answer (score 0):

> If I hit the endpoint direct with no search criteria (just api/search)
> the searchCriteria object is always instantiated and isn't null. If I
> remove [FromQuery] it does correctly default to null when no values
> are provided and only instantiated if provided in the body.

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description it would be nicer if you could share your `SearchCriteria` class details.

However, apart from that what you are experiencing is expected behaviour because while you are creating request with no value the object will always be created and the value would be null but not the object, as result this block `searchCriteria == null` will never be executed.

> Is there anyway to detect that no query params have been passed to the
> endpoint?

Yes it can be achieved, but you would need to use [ModelBindingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbindingcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0).
When you would received any null request or empty `FromQuery` then, within ModelBindingContext we have the property [bindingContext.Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-model-binder-sample) where we have to set our model property as null and on top of that, [ModelBindingResult.Success](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbindingresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0#methods) method also need to assign as `null` which will resolve your issue as expected.

Let's have a look how we can implement that in practice:

Model:

```cs
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(NullEntityBinder))]
        public class SearchCriteria
        {
            public int? MyCustomIntValue { get; set; }
            public string? MyCustomStringSearchKey { get; set; }
        }
```

Custom Model Binder:

```cs
public class NullEntityBinder : IModelBinder
    {

        public NullEntityBinder()
        {

        }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

            var model = new SearchCriteria();



            if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("MyCustomIntValue").FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                model.MyCustomIntValue = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("MyCustomIntValue").FirstOrDefault());
            }

            if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("MyCustomStringSearchKey").FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                model.MyCustomStringSearchKey = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("MyCustomStringSearchKey").FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (model.MyCustomIntValue == null && model.MyCustomStringSearchKey == null)
            {
                model = null;
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            }
            
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class QueryStringController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] SearchCriteria? searchCriteria = null)
        {
            if (searchCriteria == null )
                return Ok("This never happens...");
            else
                return Ok("Non null value directed");
        }

    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-model-binder-sample) in order to know how that works in details.

Comment: Thank for you the detailed response and solution. Sadly the search criteria has a few dozen properties with a vast number of varying types so that really seems a bit messy of an approach given that we'll have search actions for most of our entities. Since with [FromQuery] is always initializing unlike [FromBody] I just ended up adding a "HasCriteria()" method to each model that does quick checks similar to your binder for each prop and returns false if none were set and then just check that in the controller.

Comment: Also when you say: "However, apart from that what you are experiencing is expected behaviour because while you are creating request with no value the object will always be created and the value would be null but not the object, as result this block searchCriteria == null will never be executed." 
This is the part that really confuses me, why is it that the object is always created for [FromQuery] when it's not created for [FromBody]. Seems unusual they would be setup to function so differently.